# Locally modify package from pip

Tags: python, pip

I've locally installed via pip Python package in virtualenv. I'd like to modify it (not monkey patch or subclass, but deeply modify) and keep it in my source control system referencing without installing. Maybe later I'd like to package it again so I'd like to keep all files for creating package, not only python sources.

Should I just copy it to my project folder and deinstall from virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points.  One, are the changes you're planning to make useful for anyone else?  If the first, you might consider cloning the source repo, making your changes and submitting a PR.  Even if it's not immediately merged, you can make use of `setup.py` to create a local package and install that in your virtualenv.

And two, are you planning to use these changes for just one project, or on many projects?  If it's just for one project, throwing it in your repo and deeply modifying it is probably an ok thing, (although you need to confirm you're allowed to do so by the license).  If you can foresee using this in multiple projects, you're probably better off creating a repo for it, and packaging it via `setup.py`.